# How do you automate do "Copy Files" in Build Phases using a Cocoapods Post Install Script?

Tags: cocoapods, xcodeproj

I know this is a rather trivial question, but I seem to be having the worst time with this.

I've tried :

```
obj =  Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXCopyFilesBuildPhase.new(PATH, 10)
target.build_phases.add(obj)
```

But the UUID is 0 and nothing is added to the Build Phases. Can someone please help me. I know the rest of my setup is correct.

Comment: Hi, do you find out how to do this now?

Comment: Yes, you need to use new_copy_files_build_phase to create the new build phase.

Comment: Good so far, but how do you add a file to this phase?

Comment: PTAL - https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/gem/lib/earlgrey/configure_earlgrey.rb#L289

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example:

```
phase = target.new_copy_files_build_phase()

# Contrary to the docs (see http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/PBXCopyFilesBuildPhase) I believe this is not a path, but rather a code, e.g., 16 indicates to copy the file to the Products Directory.
phase.dst_subfolder_spec = "16"

fileRef = project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference)
fileRef.path = 'Server.plist'

phase.add_file_reference(fileRef)
```

Comment: agree with your comment, see constants documentation here: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Constants. `COPY_FILES_BUILD_PHASE_DESTINATIONS`