# Swift Package Manager and Xcode: Retaining Xcode Settings?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, server-side-swift

I am developing a server in Swift and using the Swift Package Manager. And find it convenient when doing my development on my Mac OS system to generate a Xcode project to use Xcode as my IDE (i.e.,  From time to time, my package dependencies have to be updated. I've been using `swift package generate-xcodeproj` to do this. My problem comes in at this point-- I have created some settings in Xcode. E.g., I've set a DEBUG flag, and I have a .plist file that is in the Copy Files Phase. These get lost when I regenerate the Xcode project. It seems I cannot simply use `swift package update` because sometimes files change in the dependencies and these don't get propagated to the Xcode project.

What I'd like is a means to separately establish Xcode settings in a file outside of Xcode, that can be imported into Xcode when I do the `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. I have not seen a way to do this.

A related question is: When I do a `swift build` I'd like those same build settings to be used.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I can't help with `Copy Files Phase`.

However I have just been toying with conditional compilation, like this:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Sandbox.xcconfig
```

#### Sandbox.xcconfig

```
FLAG_SANDBOX = -DSANDBOX
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(FLAG_SANDBOX)
```

This creates an Xcode project where `SANDBOX`is definded.

This can be used in swift code like this

```
#if SANDBOX
    print("sandbox")
#else
    print("production")
#endif
```

Comment: any suggestions for things like environment variables or for example commands to pass in?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a script or a makefile to import your settings into the generated Xcode project, each time you regenerate it. You can use [xcodeproj rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/xcodeproj/versions/0.28.2).

See [an example script](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-Builder-iOS/blob/master/Scripts/fix_client_side_xcode_project.rb).

Regarding using your settings in `swift build`, can you give an example of such a setting? In general, a makefile can read your settings file and pass the corresponding parameters to `swift build`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot shortly. An example of a setting I need to use in `swift build` is setting a DEBUG flag to conditionally compile debug only code. Also, I have a Server.plist file that needs to be made available. I make this available differently in test versus non-test builds, but it's something that's part of my Xcode build configuration.

Comment: DEBUG  flag is set by using `-c debug|release` flag of `swift build`. For other options, see [an example of a Makefile](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/GRMustache.swift/blob/master/Makefile)

Comment: I got that rubygem solution working! I've put it in as an answer below. Following your link above (http://stackoverflow.com/users/6028420/vadim-eisenberg), I can't find the Makefile example.

Comment: @ChrisPrince strange, can you access [https://github.com/IBM-Swift/GRMustache.swift](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/GRMustache.swift) ? Makefile is in this repository.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @[vadim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6028420/vadim-eisenberg)'s answer above, here's a [xcodeproj rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/xcodeproj/versions/0.28.2) solution to the first part of my question:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# Tweak the .xcodeproj after creating with the swift package manager.

# Resources: 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527782/swift-package-manager-and-xcode-retaining-xcode-settings/41612477#41612477
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072937/add-run-script-build-phase-to-xcode-project-from-podspec
# https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-Build/blob/master/build/fix_xcode_project.rb
# http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/Xcodeproj%2FProject%2FObject%2FAbstractTarget%3Anew_shell_script_build_phase
# http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/AbstractTarget
# https://gist.github.com/niklasberglund/129065e2612d00c811d0
# https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367048/how-do-you-automate-do-copy-files-in-build-phases-using-a-cocoapods-post-insta?rq=1

require 'xcodeproj'

path_to_project = "Server.xcodeproj"
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(path_to_project)

# 1) Add Copy Files Phase for Server.plist to the Products directory for Server target
target = project.targets.select { |target| target.name == 'Server' }.first
puts "Add Copy Files Phase to #{target}"
phase = target.new_copy_files_build_phase()

# Contrary to the docs (see http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/Xcodeproj/Project/Object/PBXCopyFilesBuildPhase) I believe this is not a path, but rather a code, e.g., 16 indicates to copy the file to the Products Directory.
phase.dst_subfolder_spec = "16"

fileRef = project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference)
fileRef.path = 'Server.plist'

phase.add_file_reference(fileRef)   

# 2) Add in script phase for testing target-- because I haven't figured out to get access to the Products directory at test-run time.
target = project.targets.select { |target| target.name == 'ServerTests' }.first
puts "Add Script Phase to #{target}"
phase = target.new_shell_script_build_phase()
phase.shell_script = "cp Server.plist /tmp"

# 3) Add in DEBUG flag

# A little overkill, but hopefully appending a DEBUG flag in the Debug configuration for each target doesn't hurt it.
project.targets.each do |target|
    puts "Appending DEBUG flag to #{target}"

    if target.build_settings('Debug')['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'].nil?
        target.build_settings('Debug')['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = ""
    end

    target.build_settings('Debug')['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] << '-DDEBUG'
end

project.save()
```