# Set macOS target for `swift package generate-xcodeproj`?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Is there a way to set the macOS target for `swift package generate-xcodeproj` generates Xcode projects?

For example, set default target to "x86_64-apple-macosx10.12".

**Background**

Currently, the Xcode 9.2 Swift toolchain shows the following versions on the command line:

```sh
swift --version
# Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)
# Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
swift package --version
# Apple Swift Package Manager - Swift 4.0.0-dev (swiftpm-13752)
```

The result of `swift package generate-xcodeproj` is an Xcode project with a macOS target of 10.10.

*Note: the generated Xcode 10.10 target is one version up from the swift command line compiler target of 10.9. So, apparently, the default macOS targets for `swift` and `swift package generate-xcodeproj` are determined independent of each other.*

So far, any solution with [Package.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md), `--xcconfig-overrides`, or something else has been elusive.

Comment: Seeking a solution for this as well. Same applies to a better way of doing this: https://oleb.net/blog/2017/04/swift-3-1-package-manager-deployment-target/

Comment: @Klaas As FYI, I posted my workaround for both `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and `…-Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64…` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783502/set-macos-target-for-swift-package-generate-xcodeproj/48158608#48158608)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Swift evolution proposal [SE-0236](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0236-package-manager-platform-deployment-settings.md) added the configuration of a per-platform minimum required deployment target:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyTool",
    platforms: [
        // specify each minimum deployment requirement, 
        //otherwise the platform default minimum is used.
       .macOS(.v10_13),
    ],
     targets: [
        .target(name: "MyTool", dependencies: ["foo", "bar"]),
    ],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [.v5]
)
```

This results in the target "MyTool" within the Xcode project having the "Deloyment Target" set to 10.13 .

Answer (score 18):

### Swift 5.something

`swift package generate-xcodeproj` is no longer available. See the accepted answer with `platforms: [ … ]` for what currently works.

### Swift 5

Swift 5 Package manager now enables specification of the minimum required target platform with via `platforms` in `Package.swift`. ... see answer provided by Klaas.

### Swift 4

I ended up creating `swiftxcode`, `swiftbuild`, and `swifttest` bash aliases as a workaround to simplify:

1. setting the macOS target with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`, and
2. hiding [`swift build -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-…"`](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/04/swift-3-1-package-manager-deployment-target/)

**Setup**

Edit and `source` `~/.bash_profile` to add `swiftxcode`, `swiftbuild`, and `swifttest` aliases to the command line.

```sh
###################################
### Swift Package Manager (SPM) ###
###################################
alias swiftxcode="swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Package.xcconfig"
alias swiftbuild='swift build -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.12"'
alias swifttest='swift test -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.12"'
```

Edit `Package.swift` in the for the project to specify using Swift Package Manager tools version 4:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(…
```

Add `Package.xcconfig` to project folder:

```ini
/// Package.xcconfig

/// macOS Deployment Target
/// 
/// Code will load on this and later versions of macOS. 
/// Framework APIs that are unavailable in earlier versions will be weak-linked; 
/// your code should check for `null` function pointers 
/// or specific system versions before calling newer APIs.

MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12
```

*Note: Optionally, the [BuildSettingExtractor (xcodeproj → xcconfig)](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/BuildSettingExtractor) created by [James Dempsey](http://jamesdempsey.net/2015/01/31/generating-xcode-build-configuration-files-with-buildsettingextractor-xcodeproj-to-xcconfig/) can be helpful to explore other settings to add to the `Package.xcconfig` file.*

**Use**

```bash
cd to/some_project_folder/
swiftxcode     # create Xcode project
swiftbuild     # build from command line
swifttest      # build and run tests from command line
```

**Caveats**

1. `Package.xcconfig` sets Build Settings values *only at the target level* in the Xcode project.  The overall *project level* Build Settings values remain unchanged.
2. `Package.xcconfig` project values are *set the same for all targets*.  There does not appear to currently be a mechanism for the xcconfig on a per target basis.
3. Some `xcconfig` values, such as `SKIP_INSTALL`, may need to be set manually in the Xcode project.

**Roadmap**

Hopefully, the current limited `xcconfig` approach shown above will be superceded by the ability to specify custom build settings in the package manifest, as discussed in the [Swift 4 Package Manager Roadmap](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2017-January/000307.html).

> Configuration File Support
>
> We are considering adding a configuration file mechanism, which could be user-specific or package-specific, to allow customizing certain package manager behaviors. One immediate use for this would be as a temporary mechanism for passing overriding compiler flags for a package, though we hope to solve that need with a real build settings model. Other uses for a configuration file are up for consideration.

Also worth noting is that Apple's "New Build System (Preview)", written in Swift and released with Xcode 9, can use `xcconfig` files to define build settings.

**Resources**

- [Apple: Configuration Settings File (xcconfig) format](https://help.apple.com/xcode/#/dev745c5c974)
- [New Xcode Build System and BuildSettingExtractor](http://jamesdempsey.net/2017/06/13/new-xcode-build-system-and-buildsettingextractor/)
- [The Unofficial Guide to xcconfig files](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html)
- [Five Things You Must Know About Xcode 10 New Build System](https://medium.com/xcblog/five-things-you-must-know-about-xcode-10-new-build-system-41676cd5fd6c)

Answer (score 1):

In case the official swift tools do not allow some Xcode project manipulation, you may want to fall back on writing a script that will update the generated Xcode project for you.

You can use
[xcodeproj rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/xcodeproj/versions/0.28.2).
See [an example script](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-Builder-iOS/blob/master/Scripts/set_deployment_version.rb).

See a related question [Swift Package Manager and Xcode: Retaining Xcode Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527782/swift-package-manager-and-xcode-retaining-xcode-settings)

Answer (score 1):

Steps to achieve this without 3rd party tools.

1) Create **macos.xcconfig** file in **/Sources** folder with following contents

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.12
```

2) Run this command in the root of your project

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Sources/macos.xcconfig
```